# Foreach loop through Datatable Column

Tags: c#, datatable

```
OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection();
conn1.ConnectionString = (@"ConnectionString");
conn1.Open();

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();       

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlstring, conn1); 

 foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
 {
   MessageBox.Show(row["SerialNumber"].ToString());
 }
```

I am trying to get Serial Numbers from my database. I am not sure how to go about this. Am I suppose to reference my datatable somewhere within DataTable? I already set up the connection with my database. I want all the values in the column "SerialNumber" in my datatable "Warranty".

I believe a foreach is the right choice in this senario?

Comment: Does that code work?  If so,  then I'd say you've got the right solution.

Comment: Not really, I think you missed part where you load DataTable with result of your query ... you should execute cmd and load results into DataTable ... and then go with reading the table

Comment: You need a DataAdapter or a DataReader to really get the data from the database. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx) for example.

Comment: @CodingGorilla it doesnt work - but I added it to show what ive tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've opened a connection, and you have an sql command associated with that connection, but you haven't executed the command yet. And once you execute the command, you'll also need something to read the results into the DataTable.

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();  
using (var conn1 = new OleDbConnection(@"ConnectionString"))
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlstring, conn1))
{
    conn1.Open();
    dataTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
}
foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    MessageBox.Show(row["SerialNumber"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: I got an error on `dataTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());` saying `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.`

Comment: You should show us how your sqlstring looks like ... is it procedure, does it have where clause?

Comment: I fixed some syntax and it all works now - thank you everyone. Not sure why the question got so many downvotes though :/